# Why result of GetPageLabels is different from the Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, itext, page-numbering

I edit page number of pdf in Adobe Acrobat X Pro.
[Test PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxb0Du7de8igNmVPSUc3VzdPSjg/view?usp=sharing)

> - result:
>
>   - 1-FrontCover
>   - 2-FrontFold
>   - 3-i
>   - 4-ii
>   - 5-iii
>   - 6-1
>   - 7-2
>   - 8-3
>   - 9-4
>   - 10-5
>   - 11-BackFold
>   - 12-BackCover

But this result of GetPageLabels is wrong

> - page number:
>
>   - 0-FrontCover1
>   - 1-FrontFold1
>   - 2-FrontFoldi
>   - 3-FrontFoldii
>   - 4-FrontFoldiii
>   - 5-FrontFold1
>   - 6-FrontFold2
>   - 7-FrontFold3
>   - 8-FrontFold4
>   - 9-FrontFold5
>   - 10-BackFold1
>   - 11-BackCover1

C# Code:

```
objLabels = PdfPageLabels.GetPageLabels(objReader);
TextBox1.Text += "page number:" + Environment.NewLine;
if (objLabels != null) {
    for (i = 0; i <= objLabels.Length - 1; i++) {
        TextBox1.Text += i + "-" + objLabels(i) + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

How to get the correct result like Adobe Acrobat X Pro?

Comment: This appears to be reported as [early as 2008](http://itextsharp.10939.n7.nabble.com/Issue-with-GetPageLabels-td3279.html). Check the solution offered there. Also verify if your version of iText is the latest.

Comment: I replaced the latest version(5.5.6.0) of iTextSharp,
But there is still wrong part of the page code.
new result:
`0-FrontCover`
`1-FrontFold`
`2-FrontFoldi`
`3-FrontFoldii`
`4-FrontFoldiii`
`5-FrontFold1`
`6-FrontFold2`
`7-FrontFold3`
`8-FrontFold4`
`9-FrontFold5`
`10-BackFold`
`11-BackCover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small bug in `PdfPageLabels.GetPageLabels(PdfReader)`. When encountering a new  page label dictionary without a **P** (prefix) entry, it does *not* reset the current `prefix` value:

```
int pagecount = 1;
String prefix = "";
char type = 'D';
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (numberTree.ContainsKey(i)) {
        PdfDictionary d = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObjectRelease(numberTree[i]);
        if (d.Contains(PdfName.ST)) {
            pagecount = ((PdfNumber)d.Get(PdfName.ST)).IntValue;
        }
        else {
            pagecount = 1;
        }
        if (d.Contains(PdfName.P)) {
            prefix = ((PdfString)d.Get(PdfName.P)).ToUnicodeString();
        }
        if (d.Contains(PdfName.S)) {
            type = ((PdfName)d.Get(PdfName.S)).ToString()[1];
        }
        else {
            type = 'e';
        }
    } 
    ...
}
```

You can fix this by adding the following `else` clause to the `if` in question:

```
        if (d.Contains(PdfName.P)) {
            prefix = ((PdfString)d.Get(PdfName.P)).ToUnicodeString();
        }
        else
        {
            prefix = "";
        }
```

Whith this change I get I get

> ```
> page number:
>  0 - FrontCover
>  1 - FrontFold
>  2 - i
>  3 - ii
>  4 - iii
>  5 - 1
>  6 - 2
>  7 - 3
>  8 - 4
>  9 - 5
> 10 - BackFold
> 11 - BackCover
> ```

PS: The same issue is present in the Java iText version, tested in [ReadPageLabels.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/meta/ReadPageLabels.java).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping to solve my problem,
Here is my complete program.

```
public string[] ReadPageLabel(PdfReader objReader, int intPageCount)
{
    PdfDictionary objDictionary ;
    Dictionary<int, PdfObject> objTree ;
    string[] arrLabels ;
    int i ;
    char chrLabelKind ;
    string strLabelPrefix ;
    int intLableNumber ;
    //PdfPageLabels is wrong
    //arrLabels = PdfPageLabels.GetPageLabels(objReader)


    arrLabels = new string[intPageCount];

    if (objReader.Catalog.Get(PdfName.PAGELABELS) != null) {
        objTree = PdfNumberTree.ReadTree(PdfReader.GetPdfObjectRelease(objReader.Catalog.Get(PdfName.PAGELABELS)));

        chrLabelKind = 'D';
        strLabelPrefix = "";
        intLableNumber = 1;
        for (i = 0; i <= intPageCount - 1; i++) {
            if (objTree.ContainsKey(i)) { //if reset page number
                objDictionary = PdfReader.GetPdfObjectRelease(objTree[i]);
                //PdfName.S:Number Kind
                if (objDictionary.Contains(PdfName.S)) {
                    chrLabelKind = ((PdfName)objDictionary.Get(PdfName.S)).ToString()(1);
                    //PdfName.S:/R,/r,/A,/a,/e,/D,ToString()(1)get alphabet of Index=1
                } else {
                    chrLabelKind = 'e';
                }
                //PdfName.P:Prefix
                if (objDictionary.Contains(PdfName.P)) {
                    strLabelPrefix = ((PdfString)objDictionary.Get(PdfName.P)).ToUnicodeString();               
                } else {
                    strLabelPrefix = "";
                }
                //PdfName.ST:Start Number
                if (objDictionary.Contains(PdfName.ST)) {
                    intLableNumber = ((PdfNumber)objDictionary.Get(PdfName.ST)).IntValue;
                } else {
                    intLableNumber = 1;
                }
            }
            switch (chrLabelKind) {
                case 'R':
                    //I,II,III
                    arrLabels[i] = strLabelPrefix + factories.RomanNumberFactory.GetUpperCaseString(intLableNumber);
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    //i,ii,iii
                    arrLabels[i] = strLabelPrefix + factories.RomanNumberFactory.GetLowerCaseString(intLableNumber);
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    //A,B,C
                    arrLabels[i] = strLabelPrefix + factories.RomanAlphabetFactory.GetUpperCaseString(intLableNumber);
                    break;
                case 'a':
                    //a,b,c
                    arrLabels[i] = strLabelPrefix + factories.RomanAlphabetFactory.GetLowerCaseString(intLableNumber);
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    //no number kind
                    arrLabels[i] = strLabelPrefix;
                    break;
                default:
                    //1,2,3
                    arrLabels[i] = strLabelPrefix + intLableNumber;
                    break;
            }
            intLableNumber += 1;

        }
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i <= intPageCount - 1; i++) {
            arrLabels[i] = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return arrLabels;
}
```